# Appending item to dictionary from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to move a value from one dictionary to another based on the value of each key, here is the code:

```
dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':0,'d':0,'e':0}

dict2 = {}

for c in dict:
    if dict.values() > 1:
        dict2.update(c)
```

I am being given the error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: dict_values() > int()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `dict.values()` is an iterable of `dict`'s values. Of course you can't compare it to an `int`. What are you trying to do? What is the resulting `dict2` that you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `dict.values()` returns an iterable, and you can't compare that to an int. Instead, iterate over the dictionary and compare the value of each item to a number. If it fits your criteria, you set the key/value pair in the new dictionary

```
dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':0,'d':0,'e':0}
dict2 = {}

for key, value in dict.iteritems(): #use .items() if you use Python 3
    if value > 1:
        dict2[key]= value
```

`dict.iteritems()` (use `dict.items()` for Python3) will return both the key and value as iterables. 
`dict[key] = value` will add the `value` to the dictionary with the set `key`

Also, `dict` means something in Python by default [(it's a class)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) , so it's not a good idea to use it as a variable name. Unlike some languages it will let you use it as a variable name, but it will prevent you from calling the dict class.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I didn't realise dict was used by default (first time using dictionaries and its late :))

Answer (score 0):

`mydict.values()` refers to an entire list(in python2.x) and an iterable in python3.x, in your case:

```
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0] # in python2.x
```

So asking if that list or iterable is greater than 1 makes no sense.

What you want is something like:

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
    if v > 1:
        mydict2[k] = v
```

Using dict as a name for an object of type dict isn't a good idea. It clashes.
Same goes for using list as a name for a list object etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    if v>1:
        dict2[k]=v
```